# Mongoose - Does where cause a extra query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

For MongoDB and Mongoose, does this cause 2 queries because of the `where` clause? Like `findAndModify` does because it returns the whole document before modifying?

```
Model.where({ _id: id }).update({ title: 'words' })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, but neither does `findAndModify`, as in both cases the entire command is executed atomically by the MongoDB server.

To confirm, you can see the commands that Mongoose is executing by adding the following to your code:

```js
mongoose.set('debug', true);
```